# Understanding an intersection of function types in flow

Tags: javascript, facebook, flowtype

Looking for someone with an understanding of the static type checker flow to explain to me where i am taking a wrong turn here. I am trying to understand sub-typing function intersections.

I understand that sub-typing a function requires contravariant input AND covariant output, but it appears this does not answer everything.

Take for example

```
type InterT = ((number) => string) & ((string) => number);
```

via simple tests it seems that this boils down to `(number & string) => number | string`. valid subtypes include

```
declare var I: InterT;

declare var test1: ((number) => number | string) => void;
test1(I); // works

declare var test2: ((string) => number | string) => void;
test2(I); // works

declare var test3: ((number & string) => number) => void;
test3(I); // works

declare var test4: ((number & string) => string) => void;
test4(I);

declare var test5: ((number | string) => number | string) => void;
test5(I); // works 

declare var test6: ((number | string) => string) => void;
test6(I); // FAILS 

declare var test7: ((number | string) => number) => void;
test7(I);
```

Why do these last two cases fail? `string <: number | string` and `number <: number | string`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Intersection types in Flow seem to be "badly broken" (https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6482#issuecomment-421167167). I can't speak to why `test6` and `test7` fail but I would like to point out that the type `number & string` is an "impossible" type (https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/#toc-impossible-intersection-types). From the documentation:

```
// @flow
type NumberAndString = number & string;

function method(value: NumberAndString) {
  // ...
}

// $ExpectError
method(3.14); // Error!
// $ExpectError
method('hi'); // Error!
```

What we observe is that neither `number` nor `string` can satisfy `number & string`. Thus, I honestly can't figure out why `test1` and `test2` would satisfy the type `(number & string) => number | string`. I would love some clarity on how intersection types do (or should) work in Flow. For now, though, it seems like they are impractical to use because of their broken nature.