# Composable and positive contracts in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm having a problem with Flow where a given implemented `type` is restricting my object API by asking me to use only properties that are declared on the `type` instead of asking me to declare all the `type`'s properties.

I'm new to Flow so I'm probably making some basic mistake and stuff. Anyway, I have this `type` declared:

```
type Unit = {
  of(value: any): Monad,
};
```

What I'm trying to do here is to say: all objects implemented according to `Unit` must have an `#of` method that receives a given `value` and returns a `Monad`-type value.

When I implemented it on my factory no problem came up:

```
const Maybe: Unit = {
    isMaybe: (obj): boolean => { ... },
    of: (value): Monad => { ... },
};
```

But when I try to call `#isMaybe`, I get this error (on the linter):

```
flow(0|2), isMaybe (Cannot call: `Maybe.isMaybe` because property `isMaybe` is missing in `Unit` [1].)
```

Now I tried declaring `#isMaybe` on `Unit` and the error disappeared as expected. Problem is, `Unit` should be a kind of liberal interface that checks if it's implementations have `Unit` properties instead of *only* `Unit` properties.

I can't refactor - at least not that I know - `Unit` from a `type` to a `interface` because I'm composing them through `is-a` relationships:

```
type Monad = Applicative & Chain; // Monad is-a Applicative and a Chain
```

Is there any way to make a contract both positive and composable with Flow?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a very strong FP style. This repository has some very nice ideas: https://github.com/gcanti/flow-static-land/blob/master/src/Maybe.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also not too familiar with positive and composable, but I think `interface`s can help solve the problem. You can easily extend an `interface` and declare a variable as one. Check out the example below to see how you can use and extend interfaces. Note that there's no need to go through classes in this particular case.

```
type Monad = any;

interface Unit {
  of(value: any): Monad;
}

const unit: Unit = {
  of(value: any): Monad {
    return value;
  }
}

const notUnit: Unit = {};

const alsoNotUnit: Unit = {
  isMaybe(value: any): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}

interface Maybe extends Unit {
  isMaybe(value: any): boolean;
}

const maybe: Maybe = {
  isMaybe(value: any): boolean {
    return true;
  },
  of(value: any): Monad {
    return value;
  }
}

const notMaybe: Maybe = {
  isMaybe(value: any): boolean {
    return true;
  }
};

const alsoNotMaybe: Maybe = {
  of(value: any): Monad {
    return value;
  }
}
```

[Ttry Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAsg9gOwIYBMoF4pISA3AKHwEsFgIAnAMyQGNoBVBI4KAb3yijkoAoA3JABsArhABcWHAEoJ8ZCgIBfQjUQBnFsKbAJjZhjYcuvASPGSQM2IlSHOnchGDDyCKKdEFOy5flUINKAQ4YD0dKDCDVkUCP3UWITU4ADkQsN1tKKMiNRgkEAAjCH4hUQlsSwkCuDhBCGw7e0dnVyhqQTUILygfQhIyKlpoPMLoCAAPMgQUNQjM9k4ckaKSs3LpKpq67CUVeKgAW3yi2WPoTAWoJbPVsosratr6t0uHJxc3YHJPI0UAGiM3Fu5gqVjktleUGaH3cpS6v3wvn8gWCwGW5nRWUWuRuHhBGygj22LyMbxan2+8O8iNiyISHRSIXRp1GWOMwPWlWs8kaZJheO6vU4QA)

As a word of warning since I see you've used the `&` intersection type operator--intersection types are currently broken and inconsistent in Flow. I would recommend not using them for now. Most of their behavior can be accomplished via other, more correct means, such as the spread operator or `extends`.

Comment: Hello, @user11307804. Can I extend more than one interface at the same time? Like `Monad extends Applicative, Chain`? About the jargon: *positive* means *that asks you to do*, in oposition to *asks you not to do* or *asks you to do only*; by your code snippet, I think `interface`s are not positive - I say this because you have had to extend `Unit` to another `interface` - `Maybe` - in order to make use of `#isMaybe`.
My desired behavior would be to have a `interface`/`type`/whatever that says *define `#of`and whatever else you want as well* instead of *please, define only `#of`*.

Comment: About the `&`: I had no idea about it! Does the documentation makes any mention out of it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the documentation doesn't mention it (although it certainly should provide some warning). Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/55678194/11308639 (and the linked issue) for some more information.

Comment: And, yep, you [can extend multiple interfaces](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAd0BtgLmYANxQG8BfAKFElkRQGEALOUZcq8aeJZAWQHsQcACbIIAD0ghhAZzSYceAsQA0yJixBsyQA)!

Comment: And, I think `interface` is positive. The reason I created `Maybe` is because, without it, Flow will not allow you to use `#isMaybe` on a `Unit` because `Unit` is not guaranteed to have that method defined. You are always welcome to define additional methods on an instance of `Unit` (or any other `interface`) because Flow uses [width-subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/) for objects. See the next comment for an example of what I mean (length restrictions prohibit me from including it in this comment).

Comment: Positivity of interfaces, maybe: [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAsg9gOwIYBMoF4pISA3AKHwEsFgIAnAMyQGNoBVBI4KAb3yijkoAoA3JABsArhABcWHAEoJ8ZCgIBfQjUQBnFsKbAJjZhjYcuvASPGSQM2IlSHOnchGDDyCKKdEFOy5flUINKAQ4YD0dKDCDVkUCP3UWITU4ADkQsN1tKKMiNRgkEAAjCH4hUQlsSwkCuDhBCGw7e0dnVyhqQTUILygfQgB6PqhkgFEAdQBCOICEjrh0iMzMdk5uErNy6VkbNGWmpxc3Dy6jRQAaQk4BqBB8yc4cvMLio43KqGra+rddh33W9s63V6nCAA)

Comment: It does allow us to define `#isMaybe` on a implementation of `Unit`, but it does not allows such method to be called - the very linter "throws" an error as shown [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAsg9gOwIYBMoF4pISA3AKHwEsFgIAnAMyQGNoBVBI4KAb3yijkoAoA3JABsArhABcWHAEoJ8ZCgIBfQjUQBnFsKbAJjZhjYcuvASPGSQM2IlSHOnchGDDyCKKdEFOy5fgD0flAAcgCiAOoAhPiqCBpYgmpwejpQyQbsnNz8QqIS2JayNmgZ9o7Oru45EF5QigA0hJwBUCBIIFGcRGowbQBGENlmedISvXBwghDYdqVOLm7UCdVGPoRCickAdF09IP08AORIB1JAA). So... I'm not sure with what you meant.

Comment: Ah, must have not understood the definition of positive; sorry about that. I'm curious, do you know of any type systems that have this positive behavior? I'm not familiar with much outside of Flow but it's always useful to compare their approach with existing type systems. Thanks!

Comment: I know of [structural type checkings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), that is a major theory for types in which a given state is classified as per it's shape, e.g., API definition. I don't know if the implementations of structural type languages used in this languages have the property I described.
I do know that [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) follows a similar philosophy and is the inspiration for my approach. I thought `interface`s were a pattern to make use of such a structure, but I'm clearly wrong. Anyway, thank you for the clarifications!

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with what you mean by 'Is there any way to make a contract both positive and composable with Flow?' ( I'm assuming this is coming from another language? ), and I have not used flow in the way you describe; which is to define a function definition as part of a type, but I am hopeful that my approach here will help you.

The first thing I would do here is to create a 2nd type for a `MaybeUnit`

```
export type MaybeUnit = Unit &{
  isMaybe: (obj): boolean
};
```

But, once again, I am not familiar with that function being part of the type. Anytime I want a function, I would define a class ( possibly with an interface ) instead of a type. This might change your implementation to look something like:

```
interface IUnit {
  of(value: any): Monad;
}

class Unit implements IUnit {
  of(value): Monad { 
    return new Monad();
  }
}

interface IMaybeUnit extends IUnit {
  isMaybe({}): boolean;
}

class MaybeUnit extends Unit implements IMaybeUnit {
  isMaybe({}): boolean { 
    return true;
  }
}
```

Hopefully this approach will resolve your issue.

UPDATE: Adding an example of what I sometimes do with manager classes. This is a very verbose approach, and only applicable in some cases. It's also much more usable when using flow-runtime in order to test types at execution time instead of just at build time.

```
class UnitManager {

  static UnitTypes:Map<string, IUnit>;

  static RegisterUnitType( key:string, klass:Class ) {
    UnitManager.UnitTypes.set( key, klass );
  }

  static CreateUnit( unit:IUnit ):Unit {
    // test data to determine type
    let type:string = UnitManager.GetUnitType( unit );
    let klass:Class = UnitManager.UnitTypes.get( type );
    return new klass( unit );
  }

  static GetUnitType( unit:IUnit ):IUnit {
    // Magic. Your logic to determine the type based on the data provided. if you use flow-runtime, you can use instanceOf, otherwise I think you need to test if the keys exist in the data, or something.
  }
}
```

I didn't include this initially because it's not exactly clean, and will often be an anti-pattern. It is useful in certain cases, and I find myself using this mostly to just avoid circular dependencies.

Sometimes I will have it so that each class' constructor registers itself to the manager based on a static 'name' constant in it's class.

Comment: Hello, Steven. Thank you for your answer. With "composable" I mean "that can be composed", e.g., something like `intersection types`; with "positive" I mean "that asks you to do" - what is the oposite of "negative" or "that forbids you to do" or, like in this situation, "that asks you to do *only*".

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, that helps me understand the problem. I realize now that my answer doesn't fully satisfy your question.

I'll watch this question, it's very interesting.

Comment: About your solution: I'm using factories instead of classes intentionally. Also, I could code a interface specific to `Maybe` but I also have other use cases - that do not share `#isMaybe`. It *is* possible  to do that but I would like a more elegant solution - if such a solution exists.

Comment: I can't think of a solution for you here without creating class' for each of your implementations, but I also don't use Factories, I would instead use a Manager. Possibly even map the various class' to static keys in my manager. I'm just not familiar enough with Factories in Flow to help you here, but I'm happy to learn along with you.

Comment: Can you post this Manager solution?

Comment: @HenriqueGuerra added, but I don't know that it will help you at all or not.