# Flow Polymorphic Type Definition for Binary and Unary Functional Expressions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I'm trying to define a generic type that is polymorphic for both binary and unary curry functions with Flow. So far it only works when the type definition only contains one of these definitions. For example this will work:

```
type tOr<X, Y, XX: X, YY: Y> =
  & (((...a: [XX]) => YY) => ((...b: [XX]) => YY) => (x: XX) => boolean)

const Or2: tOr<number, Array<number>, *, *> = f => g => x => !!f(x) || !!g(x);
```

This reports errors:

```
type tOr<X, Y, XX: X, YY: Y> =
  & (((...a: [XX]) => YY) => ((...b: [XX]) => YY) => (x: XX) => boolean)
  & ((a: XX => YY, b: XX => YY) => (x: XX) => boolean);

const Or: tOr<number, Array<number>, *, *> = (f, g) => (x) => !!f(x) || !!g(x);
```

> const Or: tOr, *, *> = (f, g) => (x) => !!f(x) || !!g(x);
>                ^ Cannot instantiate `tOr` because function type [1] is incompatible with number [2] in type argument `XX`.

The full expression is on [Flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBMDyBOAeAGgGigTXc5AuKamG+GAfFALwBQUUAZFABTMB0bAhvgNo4C6AlJXIYMgiuVZsARtz5jhooUwAe+HPKhSA9loA2EdgDt+Nek0acCyJSPQyrNxeJVrkG7XoPGA3FSoBjLUMAZ2AoBHw4JEMAVwBbKQh4dABBeHh2EERYhKTSdAAqQvIKJgAzdABzDUZlDQBCerLawQAfVqhGypbfQJCwhAAmSIRs+MTkqDSMrJyJ-KgixZKoMqVKpWUlRua6qHbO+u663yA)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55678194/11308639 for a discussion on the risks of using intersection types. It's not a satisfying answer but Flow isn't setup to allow for "overriding" functions with multiple type definitions (since JS itself doesn't really do function overriding in the same way C++ or other languages do). If it works for you project, splitting this into two functions would be the easiest approach with respect to Flow, and ignoring Flow would be the easiest approach with respect to keeping the same code behavior.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more investigation I found that Flow can overload a polymorphic type by using the disjoint union. This was tested without error on the Flow try editor.

```
type tOrUnary<X, Y, XX:X, YY:Y> =
  & (((...a: [XX]) => YY) => ((...b: [XX]) => YY) => (x: XX) => boolean)

type tOrBinary<X, Y, XX:X, YY:Y> =
  & (((a: XX) => YY, (b: XX) => YY) => (x: XX) => boolean);

type ORpoly<X, Y, XX:X, YY:Y> = tOrUnary<X, Y, *, *> | tOrBinary<X, Y, *, *> ;

const Or1: tOrBinary<number, Array<number>, *, *> = (f, g) => (x) => !!f(x) || !!g(x);
const Or2: tOrUnary<number, Array<number>, *, *> = f => g => x => !!f(x) || !!g(x);
let OR: ORpoly<number, Array<number>, *, *> = Or1;
OR = Or2;
```